# How to let org-tree-to-indirect-buffer narrow to the current subtree

Tags: org-mode

How to let org-tree-to-indirect-buffer narrow to the current subtree instead of opening a new frame with the narrowed tree? Should I customize some variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `org-indirect-buffer-display`.

You should check the doc of this variable directly by `C-h v org-indirect-buffer-display`:

```
org-indirect-buffer-display is a variable defined in ‘org.el’.

Its value is ‘other-window’

How should indirect tree buffers be displayed?

This applies to indirect buffers created with the commands
‘org-tree-to-indirect-buffer’ and ‘org-agenda-tree-to-indirect-buffer’.

Valid values are:
current-window   Display in the current window
other-window     Just display in another window.
dedicated-frame  Create one new frame, and re-use it each time.
new-frame        Make a new frame each time.  Note that in this case
                 previously-made indirect buffers are kept, and you need to
                 kill these buffers yourself.
```